# SNMP : CPU percentage calculation

Tags: linux, centos, monitoring, snmp, cacti

Monitoring my system cpu usage through SNMP data. snmp output data is been inserted into influxdb as Raw value. I'm not sure that the below formula is correct one to calculate it

CPU_usage = [ ssCpuRawUser / (ssCpuRawUser+ssCpuRawNice+ssCpuRawSystem+ssCpuRawIdle+ssCpuRawSoftIRQ) ] * 100

But I'm not getting correct output. I matched output value with Cacti.

Someone please give a exact command for Raw snmp cpu usage percentage calculation

Need a output for below sets:
idle CPU %
User CPU %
System CPU %
Nice CPU %

Comment: Can you list the exact schema and query that you're using?

Comment: @MichaelDesa I have an issue on influxdb forum with more detailed info. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/influxdb/SPHgKiTorfE.  Please have a look and share your advice on this.

Comment: @MichaelDesa , Any idea on this ?. Kindly help me

Comment: What's the output of `SHOW SERIES` for your database?

Comment: this is the show series output https://paste.ubuntu.com/23668295/

Comment: And whats the exact query that you're running?

Comment: SELECT mean("user")  / sum(value) * 100 FROM "ucd_cpu" WHERE "hostname" = 'localhost' this is the command I run to find value for user CPU percentage. but its not showing correctly.

Comment: Whats your schema look like? What fields do you have? What do they correspond to?